# Should the 5th wheel be included in the tire rotation?

Tags: tires, jeep, wrangler, spare-tire

I didn't see this question asked so thought it might make a good one. If you have a visible 5th wheel that is full size like the spare on a Jeep Wrangler should that spare be included in the tire rotation? If the full size spare should be included how should the rotation be performed compared to a normal rotation?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several patterns of rotation for vehicles.

When a vehicle has a space saver spare then patterns of side to side, cross  or front to rear are applicable.

As you have a full size spare then that can be included in the rotation and is what I would consider normal.

See

[image]

The patterns for all these with details can be found here :

[Tire swapping patterns](https://www.tirerack.com/tires/tiretech/techpage.jsp?techid=43)